# When was the game mechanic of online invasion of single player mode first introduced?

Tags: gaming-history

It seems to me that more and more games in the last few years feature an invasion mode for their campaigns, in which another player (usually in a hostile role) enters the single player campaign mode of someone else.

When was this game mechanic of online (or maybe offline) invasion of an otherwise single player mode first introduced in video games?

Comment: *When was the game mechanic of online invasion mode first introduced?* If someone can come join your single player game, then it isn't single player mode.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The feature you're referring to is called *invasion multiplayer*.

The game that introduced this seems to be Demon's Souls from **2009** (lauded for introducing the core characteristics of the Souls game series):

> Online multiplayer allows both player cooperation and world invasions featuring player versus player combat.
> <sup>[source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demon%27s_Souls)</sup>

It is worth nothing that this gameplay mechanic was being developed two years earlier by Arkane, but [the game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Crossing_(video_game)) which had it implemented was never released:

> In 2007 Arkane Studios began creating a game called The Crossing [..]. The team behind the game wanted to include a mechanic they called “cross-player”, in which host players would have some enemy characters in their game controlled by other human players and give players a reprieve from the usual multiplayer experience.
> Unfortunately, the game was never released due to publisher and financial issues, but the cross-player mechanic was definitely a predecessor to invasion mechanics in future titles.
> <sup>[source](https://gamerant.com/invasion-mechanic-needed-more-games-dark-souls-deathloop-good/)</sup>

Arkane did pick up some core elements of The Crossing for [Deathloop](https://www.ign.com/articles/deathloops-invasion-pvp-mode-can-be-played-like-a-co-op-game).

---

Games that offer invasion multiplayer are:

| Title | Year | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Elden Ring | 2022 | ⨁⨺ |
| Sniper Elite 5: France | 2022 | ⨁⨺ |
| Deathloop | 2021 | ⨺ |
| Demon's Souls | 2020 | ⨁⨺ |
| Dark Souls: Remastered | 2018 | ⨁⨺ |
| Watch_Dogs 2 | 2016 | ⨁⨺ |
| Dark Souls III | 2016 | ⨁⨺ |
| Bloodborne | 2015 | ⨁⨺ |
| Metal Gear Solid V: The Phantom Pain | 2015 | ⨺ |
| Watch_Dogs | 2014 | ⨁⨺ |
| Dark Souls II | 2014 | ⨁⨺ |
| Dark Souls: Prepare to Die Edition | 2012 | ⨁⨺ |
| Journey | 2012 | ⨁ |
| Dark Souls | 2011 | ⨁⨺ |
| Demon's Souls | 2009 | ⨁⨺ |

⨁: helpful ⨺: hostile

<sup>Sources: [1](https://www.mobygames.com/game-group/gameplay-feature-invasion-multiplayer), [2](https://www.ign.com/articles/elden-ring-multiplayer-co-op-pvp), [3](https://gamerant.com/deathloop-julianna-invasions-better-dark-souls/), [4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watch_Dogs_2#Gameplay), [5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journey_(2012_video_game)#Gameplay)</sup>

Comment: Interesting how most of these games are either Souls games or Souls clones.

Comment: 9/13 of the games were created by Hidetaka Miyazaki. The Demon Souls, Dark Souls, Boodborne and Elden Ring games.

Comment: Does Journey count?

Comment: @ToivoSäwén I think so: it is basically a single player game, which others are able to invade (albeit only in a supportive role). Added.

Comment: I wonder if No Man's Sky fits the bill. Does anyone have experience with it? Is it an always-online game, or is it an open-world singleplayer experience with invasions?

Comment: Dying Light ---

Comment: @Joachim last I remember, No Mans Sky does not have this mechanic. I have not found anything about it on forums.  *PvP* does seem possible, though extremely rare since most players have it turned off.  *Dying Light 2* has a feature where you could be running around and a message pops up saying "<playerName> sent a distress signal" (or something like that).  If you accept it, you load into their game to assist (unsure if *Dying Light* has this, and unsure if you could also be hostile instead of helping since  every time I tried it, it would fail to connect).

Comment: Dying Light had the ability to join others games https://dyinglight.fandom.com/wiki/Be_the_Zombie

Comment: @n_plum "*A multiplayer feature included is a game mode known as "Be the Zombie" that allows the player to play as a particularly strong and fast infected mutant called the "Night Hunter" and invade other players' servers*" (Dying Light Wikipedia article). It seems there is no real invasion happening, as it's an online mode. Same for DL2, apparently, see [here](https://www.ginx.tv/en/video-games/dying-light-2-multiplayer-pvp).

Comment: @Joachim You're invaded during a regular single player or coop session, as long as connected to internet and don't have invasions disabled. It's not a separate "mode". How's this different from the other games?

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon If that is the case, it isn't, but I couldn't find that kind of information, only that someone can invade players already playing on a server, which would make it different.

Comment: It's peer-to-peer, no "lobby", if that's what you mean. Else I don't know how you can have multiplayer without a server.

Comment: If you're listing Watch_Dogs 2 then why isn't Watch dogs Legions isn't listed? It also has invasion mode like Watch_dogs 2 had.

Comment: Dying Lights invasion was most certainly an invasion - it wasn't a separate mode you loaded into. If I had invasions turned on, other players could spawn in as the mutant and hunt you down. Was a hostile mode, no helping.

Comment: Nioh and Nioh 2 have this feature as well

Answer (score 4):

Since you included the possibility of "invading" an **offline** game... I want for sake of completion to point out that the idea of "forcing" your way into someone else game and potentially steal their progress was seen in at least another very famous series far before Demon Soul was even in the work.

[image]

The older gamers may remember the "Here comes a new challenger" feature in Street Fighter II that allowed any challenger to join the game at any time, interrupting whatever the first player was doing and pulling them in an one-vs-one match: the winner would get to continue playing while a lost would mean a gameover. This fits the idea of "invading" the game since the competitive mode could be accessed at any time without the consent of the other player.

I don't know if other games before Street Fighter used that idea too, but the words "Here comes a new challenger" have become so popular by now that basically everyone takes this game as the first example of an arcade game that could be "invaded" by a challenger at any time.

Comment: Didn't one of the super smash brothers have something similar to this too? I think it was one of the ways to unlock characters.

Comment: @TimmyJim The line used there is somehow similar, maybe even a reference, but other than that I don't think there were more similarities. I don't remember any feature that allowed someone to interrupt the other player game in Smash.

Comment: The original smash on the N64 had the new unlockable characters show up after a match for you to fight (winning unlocked them)

Comment: @n_plum exactly, and later games had similar mechanics too. But here we are talking about a second, human player being able to initiate a challenge against the first player at any given time and even being able to "steal" the game should they win - Smash hasn't got anything similar.